# memcache + socket.io + php application to read sessions and chat with each other

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io, chat

i used multi room chat application example for node.js writed by mike in this [article](http://psitsmike.com/2011/10/node-js-and-socket-io-multiroom-chat-tutorial/).and changed it to use session data which grabed from php session handler until now

this is the part of code which i wrote until now

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    memcache = require("memcache"),
    http = require('http'),
    server = http.createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    co = require("./cookie.js"),
    php = require('phpjs'),
    codein = require("node-codein");

//check if user loggedin
// routing
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
  var cookieManager = new co.cookie(req.headers.cookie);

  var client = new memcache.Client(11211, "localhost");
  client.connect();

    user = client.get("sessions/"+cookieManager.get("sec_session_id"), function(error, result){
            var session = JSON.parse(result);
            user = JSON.parse(session.name);
            user = user.username;
            storeUsername(user);
    });

});
function storeUsername(user){
// usernames which are currently connected to the chat

var usernames = {};
io.of('/private').authorization(function (handshakeData, callback) {
  console.dir(handshakeData);
  handshakeData.foo = 'baz';
  callback(null, true);
}).io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    usernames[socket.id] = socket;
    // when the client emits 'sendchat', this listens and executes
    socket.on('sendchat', function (data) {
        // we tell the client to execute 'updatechat' with 2 parameters
    io.sockets.emit('updatechat', socket.username, data);
    });

    // when the client emits 'adduser', this listens and executes
    socket.on('adduser', function(username){
        // we store the username in the socket session for this client
        socket.username = user;
        // add the client's username to the global list
        // echo to client they've connected
        if(php.in_array(socket.username,usernames)){
            delete usernames[socket.username];
        }else{
            usernames[user] = user;
            console.log('not exist');
        socket.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', 'you have connected');
        // echo globally (all clients) that a person has connected
        socket.broadcast.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', username + ' has connected');
        // update the list of users in chat, client-side
        io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
        }
    });

    // when the user disconnects.. perform this
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        // remove the username from global usernames list
        delete usernames[socket.username];
        // update list of users in chat, client-side
        io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
        // echo globally that this client has left
        socket.broadcast.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username + ' has disconnected');
    });
});
}
server.listen(3000);
```

for example user master will connect to our chatroom and he will have his username which stored from php based application.but where is the problem now?when user master connect from 2 or 3 tab of our browser he will connect to socket server 3 or 4 times and if he post some data we have this result

```
master : hello
master : hello
master : hello
```

i want users to connect to my application just once and can post data just once.now how should i achieve that?

how should i access this users in case of private message to each other

i am so new in node.js.my bad.sorry

thanks for help in advance.+1 for all teachers

Answer (score 1):

1) You could you (seems to), var app = require('express').express();
2) On first app.get, you don't need to put 2 times JSON.parse, maybe the second JSON.parse is not what you want (are you trying to retrieve user threw that field ?)
3) MOST IMPORTANT : to make usage of room, you must use socket.join to join a room, if you don't
do it, the socket.broadcast will have no special effect...
To remove a user from a room, use socket.leave